# Run a Function on Scroll, but do not scroll on the page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a page where I have a div on top of the page's content that I want to raise like a curtain on the first scroll event, but not actually scroll up the page itself.

After the curtain div raises up, I want scrolling to function normally again.

Here is the code I'm using.  I'm basically using the slideup class to change the #header-image position to be above the top of the document, creatng the raising curtain effect.

```
$(function(){
var stickyHeaderTop = $('#header-image').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            $('#header-image').addClass('slideup');
        } else {
            $('#header-image').removeClass('slideup');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you cannot disable the scrolling the page..

Comment: @C-linkNepal Press F12 and copy/paste this into the console... `$(window).on("scroll", function() { $(window).scrollTop(0); });`

Comment: Are you saying this is an animation and you want to stop scrolling while the animation takes place?  Can you give us a clearer description of what you want?

Comment: Yes.  Imagine I have a page with two layers. I want to slide hte top layer, #header-image, up on scrolldown, revealing a bottom layer underneath it.  This bottom layer should be aligned to the top of the browser window without moving down, essentially the first scroll event makes the top layer, #header-image, move up like a curtain, while the bottom layer stays still until the top layer is moved up.

Comment: It would be easier to move the underneath layer down, whilst scrolling the top layer off the page.  I'll have a play and see if I can get something that looks nice, without being jumpy as hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick...

**html**

```
<div id="curtain">
    <div class="curtain-inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
...your content here...
</div>
```

**css**

```
#curtain {
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 1s ease;
    width: 100%;
}
#curtain .curtain-inner {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 500px;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 120px;
}
#curtain.raised {
    top: -500px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var marginTop = parseInt($("#content").css("margin-top"), 10);

    $window.on("scroll", function() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 50) {
            $("#curtain").addClass("raised");
        }
        else {
            $("#curtain").removeClass("raised");
        }
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle example**

http://jsfiddle.net/g04kb5m4/2/

What it does is reposition the content as the window is scrolled, so it appears to not move.  Once you scroll beyond the bottom of the curtain layer it is allowed to scroll as normal.

Also, the curtain layer takes up 0 height, and the `.curtain-inner` is what you want to display.  Use of `overflow: visible;` means you can see the contents of the curtain layer, despite it having a height of 0 pixels.  This is what makes the content sit at the top of the page, despite being after the curtain.

Comment: Close, but the first scroll action should make the curtain raise completely up.